# Replacing a chromebook charging port

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, chromebook

The battery port on my google Chromebook where I plug in the charger is blocked/busted.

Is there a possibility of replacing it?

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to go online, and find the housing that fits your model, and then re-solder it into place (in fact I did this on a different type of laptop a few weeks ago) it is not something that I would recommend doing unless you really know what you are doing with a soldering iron and around a motherboard.

You might have luck bringing it into a repair shop that can do this for you though.

Comment: A repair shop is the way to go (or a warranty..) Unless you absolutely know what you're doing, you could just cause more problems.

Comment: @soandos Thanks! Any site you recommend for finding that housing?

Comment: @ekaj agreed, hence the "it is not something that I would recommend" though it is possible (did it more for fun than anything else to be honest).

Comment: @Observer, try the repair shop first. If they don't have the part, they probably know where to get it (though e-bay probably has it as well).

Comment: @Observer, it would be appreciated if you marked this answer as the answer by clicking on the check mark to the left (if this in fact the answer to your question). Welcome to SuperUser